# sequelize-typescript: Many-to-many association using through table giving unique key constraint error

Tags: typescript, database, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

User.model.ts

```
import {
  AllowNull,
  BelongsToMany,
  Column,
  Model,
  PrimaryKey,
  Table
} from "sequelize-typescript";

import { Contact } from "./Contact.model";

@Table
export class User extends Model {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column
    declare username: string;

    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column
    declare email: string;

    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column
    declare password: string;

    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column
    declare displayName: string;

    @Column
    declare dateOfBirth: Date;

    @Column
    declare avatar: string;

    @BelongsToMany(() => User, () => Contact, "username", "contactUsername")
    declare contacts: Array<User & {Contact: Contact}>;
}
```

Contact.model.ts

```
import {
  Column,
  ForeignKey,
  Model,
  Table
} from "sequelize-typescript";

import { User } from "./User.model";

@Table
export class Contact extends Model {
  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column
  declare username: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column
  declare contactUsername: string
}
```

---

The above are two models which I have defined using sequelize-typescript. I am able to add a new contact to a User just fine. However, as soon as I want to add another contact to the same User, I get a unique key constraint error saying that the `username` already exists.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have both `username` and `contactUsername` in the Contact model to be a composite primary key, which should make sense for most people.

Comment: I am also facing these problems trying to implement a many-to-many relation between to enities of the same model. Have you found a solution yet? If so, it would be really helpful to awnser your question